# How to save theme prefrence using sharedPrefrence in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, sharedpreferences, android-theme

So, I'am trying to change the theme of the app using a switch and save the theme prefrence using sharedPrefrence though I have somehow manage to make it work but there are some problems.

```
`override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

       // initializing the switch and sharedPref variable
        val themeSwitch = findViewById<Switch>(R.id.theme_switch)
        val sharedpref = getSharedPreferences("theme_pref",MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = sharedpref.edit()
        themeSwitch.isChecked = sharedpref.getBoolean("theme_switch_is_checked",true)


        //checking if the switch is checked or not
        fun loadTheme(){
            val isChecked = themeSwitch.isChecked
            if(isChecked){
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
                editor.apply()
            }else{
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
                editor.apply()
            }
        }

        loadTheme()
        
        //if theme is used then change the theme and call the loadTheme() function
        themeSwitch.setOnClickListener {
            if (themeSwitch.isChecked) {
                editor.putBoolean("theme_switch_is_checked",true)
                loadTheme()
            }
            else {
                editor.putBoolean("theme_switch_is_checked",false)
                loadTheme()
            }
            editor.apply()
        }`
```

This code works but the problem I'am running into is that whenever I change the theme the values in my textview get erased and seems like the whole layout is being refreshed.